# SQL subquery to calculate frequency over average frequency

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to create a chart that will represent the performance of some stores.
The x axis will represent the total revenue of the store over the average revenue of all the stores.

And the y axis will represent the **average frequency** the customers of a specific store visit **this store** over **the average frequency** all the customers visit **all** the stores.

This is what I have tried :

```
select 
distinct [Order].shop_id 
, SUM(total) /((select AVG(o.shopTotal) 
                            from 
                            (
                            select 
                                    distinct shop_id , SUM(total) as shopTotal 
                                    from [Order] 
                                    group by shop_id
                            )o)*0.1) as revPerAvgRev

,COUNT(distinct orderno) /((select AVG(orders) 
                            from 
                            (
                            select 
                                    distinct shop_id , room, COUNT(distinct orderno) as orders 
                                    from [Order] 
                                    group by shop_id , room
                            )o)*0.1) as freqPerAvgFreq
from [Order] 
group by [order].shop_id
order by revPerAvgRev desc

select distinct shop_id ,room , count(distinct orderno)
from [Order] 
group by shop_id , room
```

I believe the average frequency that the customers visit the stores is ok.
But I cannot manage to calculate correclty the average frequency each customer visit **the** store.

**Note:** Each customer only visits one store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a little difficult to follow exactly what you want.  You ask for frequencies but the code sample is showing revenue.  You can get the proportion of revenue by using a window function to calculate the total:

```
select shop_id, shopTotal,
       cast(shopTotal as float)/ sum(shopTotal) over () as Revenue,ProportionOfTotal,
       numvisits,
       cast(numvisits as float) / sum(numvisits) over () as VisitsProportionOfTotal
from (select shop_id , SUM(total) as shopTotal, count(*) as numvisits
      from [Order] 
      group by shop_id
     ) s
```